# Does two factor authentication increase the attack surface?

Tags: authentication, web-application, multi-factor

> Would adding two factor authentication to an application increase the
>   attack surface of this application?

I think it would, since by adding complexity the likelihood of a vulnerability in my application is increased and so it opens another path for the attacker to exploit the system.

Would this be right?

Comment: yes, this is correct - more functions = more possibility for vulnerabilities

Comment: You have to ask yourself, though, is the increased attack surface worth it? Does the new function mitigate other risks? Known, tested, and mature new functions can be low-risk in comparison to the problem they are fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer the question; it depends on the implementation and/or use-case.

It's not as simple as "more functionality equals greater risk". 2-Factor authentication only ensures that there are at least two channels used as intended and thereby prove that the authentication claim is *more than likely* correct.

This defeats most of attacks made possible by eavesdropping on a transmission between parties. Assuming the implementation is secure, 2FA tremendously increases security (and to some extent authorization). However, assuming things is always a bad idea, especially in the case of information security.

Comment: But, the OP is asking about the security of the application, not the user's account.

Comment: @schroeder hence the emphasis on implementation

Comment: implementation does not affect attack surface - implementation affects risk

Answer (score 1):

Two factor authentication is a great way to help prevent unauthorized access especially if you use a product that's already been in development and had time to mature. Should you choose to roll your own 2-factor from scratch you expose yourself to many risks thus widening you attack surface. When looking for a provider I would look at something like RSA's SecurID which is a excellent implementation of 2-factor.

Comment: Isn't RSA proprietary? I think Google Authenticator is a fine, free option.

Comment: @NeilSmithline, I believe that it is too but just as an example enterprise product I mentioned RSA.

Comment: I didn't say you were wrong, just thought there were likely better options for the OP.